# Microsoft Graph API Patch Group only updates the first group of array (C#)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add two groups to a user using the Graph Api, but no matter what it only update the first group of the array, if I change the order it will update the first one, i tried to dispose the client as well but didn't work either:

```
public async void test()
    {
        var client = getGraphClient();
        string[] groups = new string[] { "sanitized-110a-455e-9a6a-sanitaed", "sanitized-3d49-48ea-8de4-sanitized" };
        string? usercreatedID = "sanitized-a5f0-4c80-8f57-sanitized"; // result.InvitedUser.Id;
        var requestBody = new Group
        {
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {
                "members@odata.bind" , new List<string>
                {
                    $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{usercreatedID}"
                }
            },
        },
        };
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            await updategroupsAsync(group,requestBody);
        }
    }
    public async Task<string>  updategroupsAsync(string group, Group requestBody)
    {
        var clientgroups = getGraphClient();
        var result = await clientgroups.Groups[group].PatchAsync(requestBody);
        clientgroups.Dispose();
        return "Done";
    }
```